# Detect if click is inside OverlayView

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, d3.js

I want to display a certain Infobox when the user clicks anywhere on the map and a different Infobox when the user clicks inside an OverlayView.

I'm adding a listener to the click event for the map object, but this event only provides a latLong param which seems insufficient to tell if an OverlayView was hitted.

```
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'click', function(param) {
        // if( an OverlayView was clicked)
        // showInfoboxForOverlayView();
        // else
        // showStandarInfobox();
    });
```

I know I can add a separate listener for the OverlayView object, but when I do this, both events are fired (the one coming from the OverlayView object and the one from the map object).

This is how I construct my OverlayView object,

```
    var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
    overlay.onAdd = function () {

        var layer = d3.select(this.getPanes().overlayMouseTarget).append("div").attr("class", "SvgOverlay");
        var svg = layer.append("svg");
        var adminDivisions = svg.append("g").attr("class", "AdminDivisions");

        overlay.draw = function () {
            var markerOverlay = this;
            var overlayProjection = markerOverlay.getProjection();

            // Turn the overlay projection into a d3 projection
            var googleMapProjection = function (coordinates) {
                var googleCoordinates = new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[1] + 0.0005, coordinates[0] - 0.0006);
                var pixelCoordinates = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(googleCoordinates);
                return [pixelCoordinates.x + 4000, pixelCoordinates.y + 4000];
            }

            path = d3.geo.path().projection(googleMapProjection);
            adminDivisions.selectAll("path")
                    .data(geoJson.features)
                    .attr("d", path) // update existing paths
                    .enter().append("svg:path")
                    .attr("d", path);;
        };
    };
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it have a class that you would be able to check for?

Comment: Not ATM. I could add it, but still I can't figure how to work it out. This is not a classic click event, I don't have a 'target' element as a param

Comment: What does your OverlayView(s) look like? Are they rectangular?  Can you determine their bounds?

Comment: Yes, they have defined boundaries.

Comment: @mcabral, Do your OverlayView(s) have defined boundaries, as in the edges of a container <div>, or do they contain irregular polygons, (like the shape of a state or province)? What exactly do the OverlayView(s) display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the **cancelBubble** flag from the global *event* object within the handler of the overlay element:

```
event.cancelBubble = true;
```

That should prevent the second click handler from triggering.

Comment: Thanks, while this worked in Chrome, it did not in FF. I ended up using event.stopPropagation() which is supported in both.

Answer (score 0):

In your `OverlayView`:

`onAdd`: remove the listener for `map`, and add the listener for the overlay.

`onRemove`: add the listener for `map`and remove the listener for the overlay.

Comment: This won't work, I need to have the map listener and the overlay listener to cover the two cases at the same time (user clicks on the map or user clicks on the overlay).

Comment: oh, I thought the overlay would cover the whole map.. :/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would work. It's not really an easy fix either.

1. Don't use google maps events at all
2. Add individual event listeners for each of the geo paths - via d3 `.on()` method
3. Create a transparent `svg:rect` the size of the whole map, sitting behind all the paths. Subscribe to click events on it. This represents a regular map click.

Comment: While this could work it seems to be a huge workaround. I settled with  stopPropagation for the event in one of the listeners, which is simpler.